# QListWidgetItem returns wrong background color

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I want to change alpha of QListWidgetItem background and foreground (text) color. I need this to implement search in the list where items grey out if do not match QLineEdit value. I get item background color (foreground the same way) with:

```
for row in range(self.mylist.count()):
    color = self.mylist.item(row).background().color()
    print(color.name())
```

But always get `#000000`. Have checked alpha of color (with `color.alpha()`) and it was always 255. When I change color with new alpha and apply it with `self.mylist.item(row).setBackground(color)`, background gets black. Probably I get color the wrong way?

Minimal reproducible example (double click on item):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def getColor(self):
    for row in range(mylist.count()):
        color = mylist.item(row).background().color()
        print(color.name())
        print(color.alpha())


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

mylist = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

item=QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
item.setText("test")
mylist.addItem(item)
mylist.show()

mylist.doubleClicked.connect(getColor)

app.exec_()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc added example, thank you

Comment: @eyllanesc I need to change alpha of background and text of QListWidgetItem from 255 to 100. And then back from 100 to 255 (on some event). I do not want change color itself, but alpha only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QBrush of the background by default the QListWidgetItem is null so the painting will not be used, that is, the background color is not painted, so the default color is the background color of the view.

In the case of the foreground, the same thing happens, but instead of not painting it, it uses the text color of the view palette.

So if you want to get the background color and text if the QBrush is null then you will have to use the view palette:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


def getColor(self):
    for row in range(mylist.count()):
        it = mylist.item(row)

        brush = it.background()
        if brush.style() == QtCore.Qt.NoBrush:
            brush = mylist.palette().base()
        color = brush.color()
        color.setAlpha(100 if color.alpha() == 255 else 255)
        brush.setColor(color)
        it.setBackground(brush)

        brush = it.foreground()
        if brush.style() == QtCore.Qt.NoBrush:
            brush = mylist.palette().text()
        color = brush.color()
        color.setAlpha(100 if color.alpha() == 255 else 255)
        brush.setColor(color)
        it.setForeground(brush)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

mylist = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
for i in range(5):
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
    item.setText("test ")
    mylist.addItem(item)
mylist.show()

mylist.doubleClicked.connect(getColor)

app.exec_()
```